# Playa field with the same data

Tags: playa, conditionals

I have a playa field into an entrie for a channel written by teachers.
I'd like to prevent when a teacher uploads the same 'link' multiple time in different lessons that the 'link' is NOT shown multiple times but only once in a summery for the student

I was thinking for a conditional like {if link == link} {/if} or would a conditional with count be in order for this.

Hope someone can help?

{exp:playa:parents channel="teacher" status="not closed"}
                    {link}
{/exp:playa:parents}

Thanks in advance

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki) already? If so, you can use its `unique` parameter to exclude duplicates. Something like this:

```
{!-- ====================================
SET
========================================= --}

{exp:stash:set_list name="links" trim="yes" parse="yes"}
  {exp:playa:parents channel="teacher" status="not closed"}
    {stash:the-link}{link}{/stash:the-link}
  {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!-- ====================================
GET
========================================= --}

<ul>
{exp:stash:get_list name="links" unique="yes"}
  <li><a href="{the-link}">{the-link}</a></li>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I wasn't using stash yet but it seems it can do a lot of things and speed up my templates.